# Type mismatch error 13

Tags: vba, ms-office, type-mismatch

I'm trying to find a code that will ignore error 13(Type Mismatch). I think the error appeared when it reaches the header, which is not an integer but a text already. This script will add spaces below based on the number in E:E, but when ever it reaches the 1st row, it will cause an error 13. Is there any way to ignore this error and continue with the next statement?

```
Worksheets("PCA Cycle").Activate
Dim r, count As Range
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Dim temp As Integer
Set r = Range("A:J")
Set count = Range("E:E")
Lastrow2 = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For N = Lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
    temp = Range("E" & N) **HERE'S THE ERROR APPEAR**
    If (temp > 0) Then
        Rows(N + 1 & ":" & N + temp).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next N
```

Comment: is this vbscript in excel?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is VBS for Excel - if that is the case, try using this:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

That will essentially resume execution when it encounters an error

This is **NOT** an ideal solution however - it may suppress other desirable errors

**UPDATE**

A more desirable solution may be this:

```
If TypeName(Range("E").Value) = "Error" Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, i got an answer. I use error handler and it solved my problem. Anyway, Thanks for answering my question. :)

```
Worksheets("PCA Cycle").Activate
Dim r, count As Range
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Dim temp As Integer
Set r = Range("A:J")
Set count = Range("E:E")
Lastrow2 = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For N = Lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
    On Error GoTo Error_handler:  **ADDED**
    temp = Range("E" & N)
    If (temp > 0) Then
        Rows(N + 1 & ":" & N + temp).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next N
```

Error_handler:  **ADDED**

```
LastRow = Worksheets("PCA Cycle").Range("F2").End(xlDown)(x1up).Row
With Worksheets("PCA Cycle").Range("F2")
    .autofill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & LastRow&)
```

Comment: so - essentially what i suggested. did you put it in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop to row 1, finish the loop at row 2.

```
'Very import - forces you to declare all variables first,
'otherwise they're created when first used opening up
'problems with variables spelt differently.
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    'Each variable must be given a data type
    'otherwise it defaults to Variant.
    Dim r As Range, count As Range
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim N As Long '< You didn't declare this variable.

    With Worksheets("PCA Cycle")

        'I can't see where either of these variables are used.
        Set r = .Range("A:J")
        Set count = .Range("E:E")

        'I prefer to use Cells rather than Range - not sure if there's a performance improvement.
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from last row to row 2.
        For N = LastRow2 To 2 Step -1
            temp = .Cells(N, 5)
            If temp > 0 Then
                .Range(.Cells(N + 1, 1), .Cells(N + temp, 1)).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next N
    End With

End Sub
```

If you think you may have text in column 5 other than in the header you can check first:
`If IsNumeric(temp) Then..... End If`